# Java 8 Stream API: how to convert a List to a Map<Long, Set> having repeated keys in the List?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I have a class with the following fields:

```
public class Item{
   private String name;
   private Long category;
   private Set<Long> containers;
}
```

What I need to do is turn a

`List<Item> items`

into a

`Map<Long/*categoryID*/, Set<Long/*Containers*/>>`

using the Java 8 Stream API.

Right now I'm able to get the same result using `Itarable` and some `if`, like this:

```
List<Item> items = getItems();
Iterator<Item> itemsIterator = items.iterator();
Map<Long/*categoryID*/, Set<Long/*Containers.ID*/>> containersByCategoryMap = new HashMap<>();

while (itemsIterator.hasNext()) {
    Item item = itemsIterator.next();
    Long category = item.getCategory();
    Set<Long> containers = item.getContainers();

    if (containersByCategoryMap.containsKey(category)) {
        Set<Container> containersByCategory = containersByCategoryMap.get(category);
        containersByCategory.addAll(containers);
    } else {
        Set<Container> containersByCategory = new HashSet<>(containers);
        containersByCategoryMap.put(category, containersByCategory);
    }
}
```

How can I get the same result using the Stream API?

I tried something like this, but obviously I got duplicate keys exception, since there are multiple items for each category...

```
containersByCategoryMap = items.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(item -> item.getCategory(), item -> item.getContainers()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since java-9 there is `Collectors.flatMapping`:

```
Map<Long, Set<Long>> map = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Item::getCategory,
                    Collectors.flatMapping(x -> x.getContainers().stream(), Collectors.toSet())));
```

Without java-9, you could do:

```
Map<Long, Set<Long>> result = items.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getContainers().stream().map(y -> new SimpleEntry<>(x.getCategory(), y)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())));
```

You can also do this with `Map#merge`:

```
    Map<Long, Set<Long>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    items.forEach(x -> map2.merge(
            x.getCategory(),
            x.getContainers(),
            (left, right) -> {
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) and its [SetMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html) interface (which is easier to use than `Map<?, Set<?>>`).

If you wanted your resulting data structure to be immutable, you could use [`ImmutableSetMultimap.flatteningToImmutableSetMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.html#flatteningToImmutableSetMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) like below:

```
SetMultimap<Long, Long> multimap = items.stream()
        .collect(ImmutableSetMultimap.flatteningToImmutableSetMultimap(
                Item::getCategory, item -> item.getContainers().stream()
        ));
```